# replace multiple inline button onclick event handlers with content security policy compliant code

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I am new to Content Security policy. I recently enabled it in my webapp:
I have a JSP where I have multiple buttons each with a different action and I was handling different button actions with onClick event of JS but CSP does not allow using inline JS like this.

Here are the buttons I have:

```
<button type="submit"     
onclick="form.action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/product/edit'"    
class="sbmt_bt"><fmt:message key="save" /></button>

<button type="submit"    
onclick="form.action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/product/delete';   
return confirm('${deleteAlert}')" class="sbmt_bt"><fmt:message key="delete"    
/></button>

<button type="submit"  
onclick="form.action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/product/add'"   
class="sbmt_bt"><fmt:message key="add" /></button>
```

What would be a CSP compliant alternative for this?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#inline-code-considered-harmful) should be a good starting point for you. As you can see in the example you will have to create a separate JavaScript file, put the code from your onclick-listeners there and reference the JavaScript file in your html file.